# Ошибка npc в Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

После установки на сервер node.js (была установлена версия 4.x) я установил все модули, но для модуля nodemailer нужна была версия node.js >= 6.0.0 С помощью n я установил версию 8.2.1 и npc стал выдавать вот такую ошибку и создал еще debug файл.

Вот его содержимое:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.2.1/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'list' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v8.2.1
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'ansi'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/ls.js:15:13)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
4 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
5 verbose cwd /var/www/Kosmo
6 error Linux 4.4.0-77-generic
7 error argv "/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm"         
"list"
8 error node v8.2.1
9 error npm  v3.5.2
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'ansi'
12 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
12 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Теперь я не могу устанавливать модули, что делать?

Comment: КО намекает что нужен модуль `ansi`.

Comment: @Aid Но уже не получается установить

Comment: Возможно это npm косячил. Судя по stack trace, он подключается именно из npm. Подключи npm, который идёт из коробки.